# GeoServer LineSymbolizer avoid overlapping and graphic bending

Tags: styling, geoserver

Under the geoserver styling, how to set the LineSymbolizer tag to avoid line-overlapping. When I am zooming out, the geoserver is arbitrarily putting one line on top of another if they are too close to each other.

Additionally, the following XML code is allowing me to use "arrow" graphics for LineSymbolizer. But how to allow these arrows to bend at the corners?

```
<LineSymbolizer>
                    <Stroke>
                        <GraphicStroke>
                            <Graphic>
                                <Mark>
                                    <WellKnownName>ttf://FreeSerif#0x279f</WellKnownName>
                                    <Fill>
                                        <CssParameter name="fill">#00B22D</CssParameter>
                                    </Fill>
                                </Mark>
                                <Size>30</Size>
                            </Graphic>
                        </GraphicStroke>
                    </Stroke>
</LineSymbolizer>
```

Answer (score 0):

We hide some line objects depending on the zoom level. For example, in small scale we show just big rivers. Try to use Zoom-based lines http://docs.geoserver.org/2.5.x/en/user/styling/sld-cookbook/lines.html#zoom-based-line .

For setting arrows' direction try to use attribute followLine http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld-cookbook/lines.html#label-following-line .

Comment: Thanks a lot but as far as I know, `followline` vendoroption can be used only for `TextSymnolizer`. If I am wrong, kindly edit the above XML style in order to use this attribute for `LineSymbolizer`.